# How to get webpack to export a dependency as separate file?

Tags: webpack

I have a webpack/React project that builds fine and creates a minified and bundled file in `dist/file.min.js`.  However, I would also like one of the javascript files for a dependency I specify with yarn (but never use in this code) to appear in that output `dist` folder as well.

In particular, I've used `yarn` to specify that the `lz-string` library is a project dependency:

`{"dependencies": {"lz-string": "^1.4.4"}}`

And would like to have webpack export `lz-string.min.js` to the dist folder as well.  In short, how do I get the following output?

```
/dist/
   file.min.js
   lz-string.min.js
```

If `lz-string` isn't used anywhere in the javascript in this code?  (I just want to copy the version I have specified in yarn to the same output folder using webpack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CopyWebpackPlugin` to do this.

Add copy plugin: `yarn add copy-webpack-plugin --dev`.  Then modify your `webpack.config.js` by adding these lines:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

config.plugins.push(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    {from: 'node_modules/lz-string/lz-string.min.js', to: ''}
]))
```